# Validar widget Entry ¿existen validaciones de entry con tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Tengo que validar por ejemplo que la persona no ingrese letras donde pide DNI y cosas así pero no encuentro validaciones para Tkinter. Acá dejo la función que actuá con los `ENTRY`:

```
def insertar_producto(self):
        # Insertar Producto boton ventana agregar / quitar Producto

        if len(self.descripcion.get()) != 0 and len(self.stock.get()) != 0 and len(self.precio_costo.get()) != 0 and len(self.precio_venta.get()) != 0:
            consult = 'INSERT INTO Productos VALUES(NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?)'
            parametros = (self.descripcion.get(), self.stock.get(), self.precio_costo.get(), self.precio_venta.get(), )
            self.ejecuta_consulta(consult, parametros)
            self.mensaje['text'] = 'Producto {} agregado correctamente'.format(self.descripcion.get())
            self.descripcion.delete(0, END)
            self.stock.delete(0, END)
            self.precio_costo.delete(0, END)
            self.precio_venta.delete(0, END)
        else:
            self.mensaje['text'] = 'Nombre , stock y Precio son requeridos'
        self.obtener_producto()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si existen, aunque terriblemente poco documentadas...

La validación se lleva a cabo mediante dos  atributos/argumentos  del `Entry`:

- **`validate`**: especifica cuándo se llevará a cabo la validación, valores:

  - **`None`**: no se valida.
  - **`"focus"`** -> se validad cuando el `Entry` toma o pierde el foco.
  - **`"focusin"`**  -> se validad cuando el `Entry` toma el foco.
  - **`"focusout"`** > se validad cuando el `Entry` pierde el foco.
  - **`"key"`** -> se valida ante cualquier modificación del contenido.
  - **`tk.ALL`**/**`"all"`** -> se valida para todo lo anterior.
- **`validatecommand`**/**`vcmd`** -> función encargada de laa validación. Hay que pasar un wrapper de TCL sobre la fucnión/método de Python, lo cual se puede conseguir con el método [`register`](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.register-method).

  **El método/función encargado de validar debe retornar un boleano siempre:**

  - Si retorna `True` el carácter ingresado se valida y se muestra en el `Entry`.
  - Si retorna `False` el carácter se descarta.

  ---

  Podemos pasar una serie amplia de argumentos al método:

  - **`'%d'`** -> tipo de acción:

    - **`1`** -> se ha insertado algo.
    - **`0`** -> se ha eliminado algo.
    - **`-1`** -> se ha ganado o perdido el foco.
  - **`'%i'`** -> indice del carácter a insertar/eliminar, si existe, de lo contrario -1.
  - **`'%P'`** -> valor de la entrada si se permite la edición.
  - **`'%s'`** -> el valor actual de entrada antes de la edición.
  - **`'%S'`** -> la cadena de texto que se inserta/elimina.
  - **`'%v'`** -> el tipo de validación actual.
  - **`'%V'`** -> el tipo de validación que activó la llamada al método.
  - **`'%W'`** -> widget, nombre del `Entry`.

Un ejemplo con todos los argumentos:

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x200")


def on_entry_validate(d, i, P, s, S, v, V, W):
    print("Tipo de acción:",  d)
    print("Indice del carácter a insertar/eliminar:",  i)
    print("Valor de la entrada si se permite la edición: ", P)
    print("Valor actual de entrada antes de la edición:",  s)
    print("Cadena de texto que se inserta/elimina:",  S)
    print("Tipo de validación actual:",  v)
    print("Tipo de validación que activó la llamada:", V)
    print("Widget:",  W)
    return True


vcmd = (root.register(on_entry_validate), '%d', '%i', '%P', '%s', '%S', '%v', '%V', '%W')
tk.Entry(root, validate="key", validatecommand=vcmd).pack(expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```

No tienes que pasar todos, pasa solo lo que necesites para validar, en tu caso, para impedir que se ingrese otra cosa que no sean dígitos, nos basta con `S`:

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x200")


def on_entry_validate(S):
    return S.isdigit()


vcmd = (root.register(on_entry_validate), '%S')
tk.Entry(root, validate="key", validatecommand=vcmd).pack(expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Perfecto !!! Muchisimas gracias !!!