# En tkinter hay manera de ingresar en un entry float ? y que se vea en la treeview float?

Tags: python, tkinter

estoy haciendo un sistema de venta y en la sección de cargar productos a la base de datos tengo entrys y treeview, el problema es que los valores o precio de los productos no siempre serán enteros pueden tener centavos entonces necesito ingresar float existe manera para esto?

Dejo aquí la función de insertar datos donde tomo los .get()  Si necesitan ver alguna otra función o los entry o la treeview avisarme por favor y muchas gracias de antemano

````
def insertar_producto(self):
        # Insertar Producto boton ventana agregar / quitar Producto

        if len(self.descripcion.get()) != 0 and len(self.stock.get()) != 0 and len(self.precio_costo.get()) != 0 and len(self.precio_venta.get()) != 0:
            consult = 'INSERT INTO Productos VALUES(NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'
            parametros = (self.descripcion.get(), self.stock.get(), self.precio_costo.get(), self.precio_venta.get(), self.combo.get(), )
            self.ejecuta_consulta(consult, parametros)
            self.mensaje['text'] = 'Producto {} agregado correctamente'.format(self.descripcion.get())
            self.descripcion.delete(0, END)
            self.stock.delete(0, END)
            self.precio_costo.delete(0, END)
            self.precio_venta.delete(0, END)
            self.combo.set("")
        else:
            self.mensaje['text'] = 'Todos los campos son requeridos'
        self.obtener_producto()    ```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Validación del Entry

Si tu `Entry` va a aceptar solo floats lo primero es validar la entrada del usuario. Por defecto el `Entry` acepta cualquier texto por lo que el usuario puede ingresar cosas que no sean un número y eso terminará en una excepción más tarde o más temprano si no lo manejamos. La solución es validar el `Entry`:

- [Validar widget Entry ¿existen validaciones de entry con tkinter?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/360618/15089)

Para obtener los datos, simplemente hacemos

```
valor = float(variable_asociada_al_entry.get())
```

o mejor, si son moneda:

```
import decimal


valor decimal.Decimal(variable_asociada_al_entry.get())
```

## El tipo de datos en la BD

Hecho ésto, en tu tabla de SQLite las columnas que almacenen dichos datos no podrán ser de tipo `INTEGER`, deberán ser en todo caso `REAL`.

No obstante, ten en cuenta que el tipo real es 8 bytes-IEEE, cuando se trabaja con moneda hay que tener cuidado con los errores de representación en coma flotante, una opción es usar directamente `TEXT` como tipo y luego en Python parsear a `decimal.Decimal` si es necesario para operar. Otra opción es usar `INTEGER` y luego parsear de forma adecuada, por ejemplo, `23.15` se almacena como `2315`.

## El TreeView

El `TreeView` no entiende de tipos, simplemente muestra cadenas. Para mostrar un `float` basta con convertirlo a cadena, redondeando o truncando si queremos o necesitamos.

## Un ejemplo completo

```
import sqlite3
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class App(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)

        self.db = "file::memory:?cache=shared"
        self.send_query("""
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS productos(
                nombre TEXT,
                precio TEXT)
            """)

        style = ttk.Style()
        style.configure('TLabelframe', background="#088A85")
        style.configure('Label', background="#088A85")
        lb_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(
            self, text="Agregar un nuevo producto"
            )
        lb_frame.pack(side=tk.TOP, expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

        tk.Label(lb_frame, text="Producto", bg="#088A85").grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.producto_entry = tk.Entry(lb_frame)
        self.producto_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="w")

        tk.Label(lb_frame, text="Precio", bg="#088A85").grid(row=1, column=0)
        vcmd = (self.register(self.on_float_entry_validate), '%P')
        self.precio_entry = tk.Entry(
            lb_frame, validate="key", validatecommand=vcmd
            )
        self.precio_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="W")

        tk.Label(
            lb_frame, background="#088A85"
            ).grid(row=0, column=2, rowspan=2, sticky="ns")
        tk.Button(
            lb_frame, text="Aceptar", command=self.aceptar
            ).grid(row=0, column=3, rowspan=2, sticky="ns")

        tk.Label(
            self, background="#088A85"
            ).pack(expand=True, fill=tk.X)
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self)
        self.tree["columns"] = ("#1", )
        self.tree.column("#0", width=220, minwidth=220, stretch=tk.NO)
        self.tree.column("#1", width=100, minwidth=100, stretch=tk.NO)
        self.tree.heading("#0", text="Producto", anchor=tk.W)
        self.tree.heading("#1", text="Precio", anchor=tk.W)
        self.tree.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
        self.update_tree()

    def aceptar(self):
        self.send_query(
            "INSERT INTO productos(nombre, precio) VALUES(?, ?)",
            (self.producto_entry.get(), self.precio_entry.get())
            )
        self.update_tree()

    def update_tree(self):
        self.tree.delete(*self.tree.get_children())
        query = "SELECT * FROM productos"
        for producto, precio in self.send_query(query):
            self.tree.insert("", "end", text=producto, values=(f"{precio} €", ))

    def send_query(self,  query,  params=()):
        with sqlite3.connect(self.db) as conn:
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute(query, params)
        data = cursor.fetchall()
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()
        return data

    @staticmethod
    def on_float_entry_validate(P):
        if not P:
            return True
        if "." in P and len(P.split(".")[-1]) > 2:
            return False
        try:
            float(P)
        except ValueError:
            return False
        return True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    App(root).pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
    root.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]